# C# How to use Interlocked.CompareExchange

Tags: c#, multithreading, interlocked, locks

My goal is the following:

There is a certain range of integers, and I have to test every integer in that range for something random. I want to use multiple threads for this, and divide the work equally among the threads using a shared counter. I set the counter at the beginning value, and let every thread take a number, increase it, do some calculations, and return a result. This shared counter has to be incremented with locks, because otherwise there will be gaps / overlaps in the range of integers to test.

I have no idea where to start. Let's say I want 12 threads to do the work, I do:

```
for (int t = 0; t < threads; t++)
{
  Thread thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startThread));
}
```

`startThread()` isthe method I use for the calculations.

Can you help me on my way? I know I have to use the Interlocked class, but that's all….

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say you have an `int` field somewhere (initialized to `-1` initially) then:

```
int newVal = Interlocked.Increment(ref theField);
```

is a thread-safe increment; assuming you don't mind the (very small) risk of overflowing the upper int limit, then:

```
int next;
while((next = Interlocked.Increment(ref theField)) <= upperInclusive) {
   // do item with index "next"
}
```

However, `Parallel.For` will do all of this a lot more conveniently:

```
Parallel.For(lowerInclusive, upperExclusive, i => DoWork(i));
```

or (to constrain to 12 threads):

```
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism  = 12 };
Parallel.For(lowerInclusive, upperExclusive, options, i => DoWork(i));
```

Comment: If I'd use Interlock.Increment, wouldn't there still be problems with the threads reading the same integer? Only the increment will go without problems, but reading the integer to do the calculation on will fail? Say the integer is 100 at the start, and all the threads start up, they all read 100, and start calculating stuff on that 100, instead of resp 100, 101, 102..

Comment: @Inigo - no; every thread is running that same while loop; the first thread gets to `Interlocked.Increment` and gets 100, the next gets 101, the next 102, etc. The implementation of `Interlocked.Increment` ensures that you will *never* get a dodgy read - it is fully atomic.

Comment: If I execute my program, I get completely random results..

http://pastebin.com/fy7tv38H